# Disable touch indicators in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, touch, long-press

I'm developing a paint app in Swing that needs to work well with Windows touch. When the user touches the JFrame, unhelpful touch indicators appear on the screen. The worst of these is the long-press square indicator, which normally produces a right-click and opens a context menu.

Most paint apps on Windows don't show the touch indicators - these include paint.net, Penbook, SketchBook, and Spirality.

Can I disable these confusing indicators in my Swing app?

[image: Screencast showing unwanted indicators]

Here is the code used in the above screencast:

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FingerPaint extends JPanel {
    Point lastPoint;
    ArrayList<Line2D> lines = new ArrayList<>();

    public FingerPaint() {
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                lastPoint = e.getPoint();
            }
        });
        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                Point p = e.getPoint();
                lines.add(new Line2D.Double(lastPoint, p));
                lastPoint = p;
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;

        // clear background
        g2.setColor(Color.white);
        g2.fill(g.getClip());

        // paint segments
        g2.setColor(Color.magenta);
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));
        for (Line2D line : lines) {
            g2.draw(line);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame f = new JFrame();
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.getContentPane().add(new FingerPaint());
            f.setSize(320, 240);
            f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            f.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```